Simple find command blocks whole server, why?
On a server running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I have an application that produces many files per day, with a cron job i'm cleaning it up by removing old files. Take this as a strict setup, not possible to change it.
So, i use this in the cronjob:
nice -n 19 find PATH_2_DIR -type f -mtime +180 -print0 | xargs -0 -n 100 rm

So it deletes all files older than 180 days.
The directory contains about 500'000 files that are younger than 180 days.
How can i make this command as non-impacting as possible? I'm running out of ideas.
The above command considers this:

it uses nice to the lowest level
it bundles 100 lines together before applying the remove command


Have you verified that the nice command does what it should do? Also, you could delete the file as soon as it's found, by using the -delete flag on the find command.

First of all, I think having an application with that produces that many file isn't a good idea. Maybe you can try saving these file's creation date into a database once they are created, and then have the script to read from that database to choose to delete those files.

In what way exactly does it "block" the whole server? note that nice only affects process scheduling - which may not help if the issue is disk i/o for example

@HoChing i know, it's horrible. But i can't change the applications behaviour. I need to solve it in the clean up command.

@steeldriver The whole server does actually not process any file accesses anymore, or at least extremely a lot less than usual. All applications running on that server freeze if that script is running.

@Jos i will try that, seems more efficient.

@ all: i will try this one now the next night: ionice -c 3 nice -n 19 cpulimit -l 20 -- find PATH_2_DIR -type f -mtime +180 -delete, this will also limit the I/O and CPU load. Maybe this helps.
